# Multiple Environment Variables in AWS Codebuild with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

I am using Terraform to provision AWS CodeBuild. In the environment section, I have configured the following:

```
  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"

    environment_variable {
      name  = "SOME_KEY1"
      value = "SOME_VALUE1"
    }

    environment_variable {
      name  = "SOME_KEY2"
      value = "SOME_VALUE2"
    }

  }
```

I have more than 20 environment variables to configure in my Codebuild Project.

Is it possible to create a list and define a single environment_variable parameter to configure all environment variables?

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? You could use `dynamic` blocks in Terraform 0.12+ to do this if you had a map of environment variables or a list of maps.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yeah, I am using terraform 0.13.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could achieve this by using [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks).

```
variable "env_vars" {
  default = {
    SOME_KEY1 = "SOME_VALUE1"
    SOME_KEY2 = "SOME_VALUE2"
  }
} 

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "test" {
  # ...

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:3.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"

    dynamic "environment_variable" {
      for_each = var.env_vars
      content {
        name  = environment_variable.key
        value = environment_variable.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will loop over the map of `env_vars` set in the locals here (but could be passed as a variable) and create an `environment_variable` block for each, setting the name to the key of the map and the value to the value of the map.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me to take the list of environment variables from the variables section rather than the locals?

Comment: That's a pretty trivial change but I've made it nonetheless. In general you shouldn't expect answers to 100% solve your problem and instead deal with the very specific issue you had (in this case how to loop over the `environment_variable` block). Whether the input is a variable or a local isn't all that important.